# MVC: Calling action methods from other areas in my controller to my view beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, view

I am using MVC-Viewmodel EF Model First, I am trying to make 2 forms in my View, one for CREATE and the other one for DELETE.
But I cant get it to work... I get this error:

```
 There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Sname'.
```

I think this happens beacuse I have this code in my DeleteSubjectType for the dropdownlist and    its suppose to be there since im using 2 forms. Somehow the action DeleteSubjectType aint working in my form.

I would appreciate if someone could take a look at my code:

This is my controller with my actions that I want to use in my view beginforms:

```
public ActionResult CreateSubjectType()
{
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateSubjectType(CreateViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SubjectType s = new SubjectType();
        s.Sname = model.Sname2;                            
        Arep.addsubject(s);
        Arep.save();
        return RedirectToAction("CreateSubjectType");
    }
    return View(model);
}


public ActionResult DeleteSubjectType(int id)
{
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    List<SubjectType> subjectypes = Arep.getallS();
    model.SubjectTypes = new SelectList(subjectypes, "SID", "Sname");

    SubjectType SubjectTypeToDelete = Arep.getbysid(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed2(int id)
{
    SubjectType SubjectTypeToDelete = Arep.getbysid(id);
    Arep.DeletSubjects(SubjectTypeToDelete);
    Arep.save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

This is my view:

```
@model NKI3.ViewModels.CreateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSubjectType","Admin",FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Skapa ny utvärderingsobjekt</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sname2, "Välj ny utvärderingsobjekt")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sname2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sname2)
        </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Lägg till" />
        </p>
        </fieldset>

    }  
         @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSubjectType","Admin",FormMethod.Post))
         {   

            <fieldset>  
            <legend>Ta bort utvärderingsobjekt</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sname, "Befintliga Utvärderingsobjekt")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.Sname, Model.SubjectTypes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sname)
            </div>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Ta bort" />
            </p>    
            </fieldset>
         }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka", "Index")
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? That is too vague and does not give those looking much to work off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it is not clear to which of the two GET actions that you have shown is this view associated: is it the `CreateSubjectType` action or the `DeleteSubjectType` action? Or even maybe some other action which you haven't shown?

If we consider that it is the `CreateSubjectType.cshtml` then you have a problem because in this view you are attempting to create a dropdownlist in the delete form for the `Sname` property. Except that in your `CreateSubjectType` you never initialized the `SubjectTypes` property of your view model to a SelectList as you did in the `DeleteSubjectType` action.

So make sure that you properly initialize this property:

```
public ActionResult CreateSubjectType()
{
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    List<SubjectType> subjectypes = Arep.getallS();
    model.SubjectTypes = new SelectList(subjectypes, "SID", "Sname");
    return View(model);
}
```

Also your delete form seems to be posting to the `DeleteSubjectType` action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSubjectType","Admin",FormMethod.Post))
```

except that on your controller I see:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed2(int id)
```

instead of:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteSubjectType(int id)
```

which I guess you were forced to do to avoid the overload resolution conflict you had with the GET action with the same name. In this case you could do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteSubjectType(int id, FormCollection fc)
```

Comment: It is the CreateSubjectType.Cshtml, the reason why I typed it in the DeletSubjectType is beacuse the user needs to select a value and then delete it, it has nothing to do with the create action, am i thinkin wrong here?

Comment: I attempted to initialize the subjectypes property of my view model to a SelectList, but then I don't know what to do with the DELETE POST, Since I want both forms to work in my CreateSubjectType.cshtml view

Comment: @RammtinAvar, I don't understand your question. What's the problem with the DELETE POST. You should rename it as I explained in my answer or modify the Html.BeginForm helper to point to the correct action name. Also you seem to be redirecting to `Index` but I don't see an Index action in your controller. Maybe you meant redirecting to `CreateSubjectType`?

Comment: I just saw your edit, yeah I changed the name of my DELETE POST.  I have changed everything as you said. When I ran the debugg and tried to delete an subjectype I recieved this error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteSubjectType(Int32, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection)' in 'NKI3.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameternamn: parameters

Comment: @RammtinAvar, well, your DELETE POST action expects an id parameter. I don't see you passing it anywhere in the view. You could either pass it in the `Html.BeginForm()` helper as a route parameter or include a hidden field.

Comment: I tried  @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSubjectType","Admin",new { id ="id" },FormMethod.Post)) but it aint working :S

Comment: @RammtinAvar, of course that it won't work. You need to pass an integer because your id parameter variable is declared as int: `@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSubjectType","Admin",new { id = "123" }, FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: Ah okey, but the ID has to choosen by the user selecting a subjecttype in the dropdownlist

Comment: @RammtinAvar, ah, alright, I see. Now it's more clear. Well in this case you should remove the `id="123"` route parameter from your Html.BeginForm call and then rename the action parameter of your delete POST action to `sname`: `[HttpPost] public ActionResult DeleteSubjectType(string sname, FormCollection fc)` because that's what you used for your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're slightly misunderstanding MVC.  The error you're getting is happening on this line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.Sname, Model.SubjectTypes)
```

And the reason is that you're not populating Model.SubjectTypes when you're rendering the view.  So I'll walk you through how the system interprets your code:

A request is made to your controller, for the Action "CreateSubjectType".  You set the model to a new CreateViewModel and return the view you've listed out.  When the view is rendering, Model.CreateSubjectType is null.  You can debug and place a breakpoint on the line I showed you above to see for yourself.  What you need to make the dropdown work is move these two lines into your CreateSubjectType action:

```
List<SubjectType> subjectypes = Arep.getallS();
model.SubjectTypes = new SelectList(subjectypes, "SID", "Sname");
```

The way you have it now, this action only executes once you POST the Delete form.

Comment: To be clear, I think there are other problems with your code, but this solves the issue that you posted about.  I would suggest walking through some MVC tutorials slowly and methodically and getting comfortable with everything until the point you feel you could teach it to someone else.